# How to listen to previous screen Listener when navigate to a new Page?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, gesture-recognition

I have a question about gestures.

I have a button that triggers to show a Dialog when long-press, choose the option when onMovePointer, and close the dialog when the user releases the pointer. Imagine it just like peek and drag to choose.

This is my code:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation,
            secondaryAnimation) {
          return IgnorePointer(
              child: OnMoveDialog());
        },
        opaque: false));
  },
  child: Text('Show dialog'),
```

[image: Here is what the widget tree looks like.]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use **GetX** state management and instead of using listener use **observation** variables
for more info check this link
https://pub.dev/packages/get

if you want to insist on pure dart you have to use global listeners and notifier.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I want to use pure flutter, so it don't depend on a package

Comment: @KhoaLe I cant understand what you need specifically but plz see this link ill hope it help you https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-draggable-and-dragtarget-in-flutter-487919f6f1e4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigator API to return the modal result.

- Refer to [return data from a screen documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Documentation shows example with pages, but the same works for modal/dialog pages

#### Page Widget

In your case, on your ElevatedButton, wait for the Navigator response:

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  /// ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
        /// Wait for the result with `await Navigator...` and store it on a variable
        final result = await Navigator.of(context).push<String>(
          PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
              return IgnorePointer(
                child: OnMoveDialog(),
              );
            },
            opaque: false,
          ),
        );

        if (result == 'option-1') { /* Handle option 1 */ }
        if (result == 'option-2') { /* Handle option 2 */ }
      },
      child: Text('Show dialog'),
    );
  }

  /// ...
}
```

#### Dialog Widget

In your modal widget, return the value when popping

```
class _MyModalState extends State<MyModalWidget> {
  /// ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Pseudo Widget, is just to examplify your modal behavior
    return MyModal(
      children: [
        Button(
          'Option 1', 
          /// Here the magic happens, you need to pop the result
          onTap: () => Navigator.pop<String>('option-1'),
        ),
        Button(
          'Option 2', 
          /// Same here, remeber: you can receive this callback as arguments
          onTap: () => Navigator.pop<String>('option-2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  /// ...
}
```